# git-filter-branch: leave directory structure unchanged

Tags: git

I have a directory structure in my repository:

```
|-repository/
|  |  |-repository/fileOne
|  |
|  |-subOne/
|  |  |-subOne/fileTwo
|  |
|  |-subTwo/
|     |-subTwo/fileThree
```

I want to move the directory `subOne` into a different repository. To do that, I'm separating `subOne` using `git-filter-branch` like so:

```
$ git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter subOne --prune-empty
```

This leaves me with a branch history that looks like this:

```
$ git log --oneline
0c0ea11 subOne history
6318bba subOne history
c96fddb Initial commit
```

This is exactly what I want; from another repository I can do a `git fetch` and `git merge`, which adds `subOne` and history into the other repository. That's great.

However, `git-filter-branch` has removed `subOne`. Checking the directory structure on my branch:

```
$ ls
fileOne
$ pwd
/this/is/a/path/repository
```

`pwd` **should** read: `/this/is/a/path/repository`, but `ls` should show `subOne` inside the repository. What I've got instead is the files from `subOne` moved upwards, and the directory removed.

How can I extract `subOne` without losing the directory?

Comment: I _think_ filter-branch might call `sh` instead of `zsh`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> pwd should read: /this/is/a/path/repository, but ls should show subOne inside the repository. What I've got instead is the files from subOne moved upwards, and the directory removed.

It turns out this is the *default operation* of `git-filter-branch --subdirectory-filter`. Quoting from `man git-filter-branch`:

> The result will contain that directory (and only that) as its project root.

**To fix this**, I want to shift everything in `/` to `/subdirectory`. Luckily, there's a piece of voodoo-looking code in `man git-filter-branch`, under `EXAMPLES`:

> ```
> To move the whole tree into a subdirectory, or remove it from there:
>        git filter-branch --index-filter \
>                'git ls-files -s | sed "s-\t\"*-&newsubdir/-" |
>                        GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new \
>                                git update-index --index-info &&
>                 mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"' HEAD
> ```

EDIT: **THIS WILL NOT WORK ON MAC OS X**. See my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525834/pre-pend-word-to-the-last-word-of-a-line) for more information. `BSD sed` is not the same as `GNU sed`, which is annoying. To run that example on OS X, change `sed` to `gsed`; the filter then works quite well.

Comment: Use `brew install gnu-sed` to get gsed on OSX

Comment: Or use `port install coreutils` if you prefer MacPorts on OSX.

Comment: Or, as `man git-filter-branch` recommends, _Please use an alternative history filtering tool such as [git filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/)._