# pre-pend word to the last word of a line

Tags: sed

I want to pre-pend a directory name to the last word in a line. The line has the following format:

`100644 bfadfab6f98b8fa1e9989fe16b2bf0fb13ffd39e 0^IoneFile$`

where `^I` denotes a `tab`, and `$` denotes the end-of-line. This line is generated by `git ls-files -s`.

I want a `sed` command to prepend `one/` to the filename in this line, like so:

`` `100644 bfadfab6f98b8fa1e9989fe16b2bf0fb13ffd39e 0^Ione/oneFile$ ``

Some of the lines that I've tried, and their corresponding outputs:

1. Match the longest string of characters that are not `\t` followed by `$`; append `one/`:

   ```
   $ git ls-files -s | sed 's|[^\t]*$|one/&|'  
   one/100644 bfadfab6f98b8fa1e9989fe16b2bf0fb13ffd39e 0   oneFile
   ```
2. Match the longest string of characters that are not `\t` or `' '` followed by `$`; pre-pend `one/`:

   ```
   $ git ls-files -s | sed 's|[^\t ]*$|one/&|'
   100644 bfadfab6f98b8fa1e9989fe16b2bf0fb13ffd39e one/0   oneFile
   ```
3. Match the longest string of characters that are not horizontal whitespace, prepend 'one/':

   ```
   $ git ls-files -s | sed 's|[^[[:blank:]]]*$|one/&|'
   100644 bfadfab6f98b8fa1e9989fe16b2bf0fb13ffd39e 0   oneFilone/e
   ```

I've basically tried a whole bunch of things matching for:

- `[^\t ]*$|one/&`
- `[^[[:space:]]]*$|one/&`

and the ones listed above. The closest I can get is to have `oneFilone/e`, which was `[^[[:blank:]]]*$|one/&|'`, or to pre-pend to the `0`, but I can't seem to quite get what I want.

EDIT
Because a few people have commented / posted answers, none of which work for me, I figured I'd add: I am using Mac OS X 10.7.3. The version of `sed` I'm not completely sure of (if anybody knows a way to get it feel free to add a comment to that effect) - the `man sed` page says it's a BSD sed. I'm not sure how different that is to `GNU sed`, if any.

I'm also using `zsh`, with `oh-my-zsh` running (prettymuch unmodified). I have turned on `extended_glob` (`setopt extended_glob`).

I've commented with my results for the answers people have given; I assume they are run on a Linux distribution? I don't have access to a non-OS X system tonight, but I will re-run any answers tomorrow; maybe it's just my `[shell|OS|bad karma]` that isn't letting them work for me.

EDIT Again:

So I've tested on a Ubuntu system, and the (1) above does work. I'd love a working version for my Mac, though.

Final EDIT:
Thanks to all who answered with working equivalent commands. It turns out that my first one **does** work, but not with `BSD sed`. I do, however, have `gsed` available (thanks for pointing that out!) which makes these all magically work.

Comment: hmm, your first option seems to work for me (I made a new git repository, committed a file, and used the exact command in your option 1). You might also try `sed -r 's|([^\t]+)$|one/\1|'` which uses explicit backreferences (-r switch to use "normal" regex).

Comment: Worked for me too on msysgit, actually 1 and 2 worked for me.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee `sed -r` gives `sed: illegal option -- r`. I'm attempting to work out what version of `sed` I'm using - best guess based on the man page is "BSD sed" (I'm using Mac OS X).

Comment: Oh, Mac OS X has a different version of sed (I'm using the GNU one). From memory, you can use `-E`. (Or, `ssed` with `-r`).

Comment: @mathematical.coffee Awesome - with `-E`: `$ git ls-files -s | sed -E 's|([^\t]+)$|one/\1|'` which gives me `one/100644 bfadfab6f98b8fa1e9989fe16b2bf0fb13ffd39e 0 oneFile`.

Comment: @macduff Maybe it's just something I'm running which isn't playing nice - `zsh`, `osx`, my version of `sed` or just bad karma. I did think I had the right regex, though, so I'm glad it works for somebody.

Comment: From the output you've been getting, it looks like your shell is not interpreting that character as a tab `\t`, but as something else. Perhaps your shell converts `\t` to 4 spaces?

Comment: @mathematical.coffee The second example in the question should cover that - I matched for `[^\t ]`, which got me prepending to the `0` - only one block-of-whitespace off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simpler, but seems to work:

```
echo -e '100644 bfadfab6f98b8fa1e9989fe16b2bf0fb13ffd39e 0 oneFile' | sed -e 's/\([a-zA-Z]\+\)$/one\/\0/g'
100644 bfadfab6f98b8fa1e9989fe16b2bf0fb13ffd39e 0 one/oneFile
```

It should work with a tab just before oneFile also.

Comment: $ git ls-files -s | sed -e 's/\([a-zA-Z]\+\)$/one\/\0/g'
100644 bfadfab6f98b8fa1e9989fe16b2bf0fb13ffd39e 0 oneFile

Comment: That's not the regex I posted! `git ls-files -s | sed -e 's/\([a-zA-Z]\+\)$/one\/\0/g'
100644 e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391 0       one/oneFile`

Comment: Oh, I do apologize, my mistake. I don't get it working for the one you *did* post, though. Yours works on the Ubuntu box I got onto - just not on Mac OS X. I think my `sed` version messes things up.

Comment: Ah! That explains it : ) Do you have 'gsed' available?

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
git ls-files -s | sed -e 's|\t\(.\+\)$|\tone/\1|g'

100644 345242cb0c4e9bb01a6fef9947f4342ff2f68553 0       one/ExView/resource.h
```

would have been

```
100644 345242cb0c4e9bb01a6fef9947f4342ff2f68553 0       ExView/resource.h
```

I've also had trouble when I got strange new line problems.  I doubt this is your problem, but in the past, `git ls-files -s | tr -d '\r' | ...` has been helpful for me.

Comment: You've understood perfectly :) Except that isn't working for me: `git ls-files -s | sed -e 's|\t\(.\+\)$|\tone/\1|g'` gives `100644 bfadfab6f98b8fa1e9989fe16b2bf0fb13ffd39e 0 oneFile`.

Comment: I know this is crazy, but what about escaping the `/`, like `\/`

Comment: `$ git ls-files -s | sed -e 's|\t\(.\+\)$|\tone\/\1|g'` - no such luck, I'm afraid. I don't get it appended anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

unable to test right now, but you're using too many brackets with the character classes.

```
[^[[:space:]]]*$|one/&
```

should be

```
[^[:space:]]*$|one/&
```

With the extra brackets, you get just the characters '[',':','s','p','a','c','e',']' -- explaining why the dir is inserted before the last 'e'

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (or am I missing something?):

```
echo -e "100644 bfadfab6f98b8fa1e9989fe16b2bf0fb13ffd39e 0\toneFile" | sed 's/\t/&one\//'
100644 bfadfab6f98b8fa1e9989fe16b2bf0fb13ffd39e 0       one/oneFile
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do exactly this but did not have gsed around...

The only issue is that OS X sed does not recognise \t as a TAB character, as explained [here](http://azaleasays.com/2014/03/07/os-x-sed-does-not-recognize-tab-character/). You have to use an actual TAB character. Use Option 1 in the original post, but instead of typing `\t`, press `Ctrl+v` followed by the `Tab` key. This is hard to copy and paste here, so you will have to do it yourself. :-)

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398395/how-can-i-insert-a-tab-character-with-sed-on-os-x).