# Insert space after period using sed

Tags: regex, macos, sed

I've got a bunch of files that have sentences ending like this: `\@.Next sentence`. I'd like to insert a space after the period.

Not all occurrences of `\@.` do not have a space, however, so my regex checks if the next character after the period is a capital letter.

Because I'm checking one character after the period, I can't just do a replace on `\@.` to `\@.`, and because I don't know what character is following the period, I'm stuck.

My command currently:

```
sed -i .bak -E 's/\\@\.[A-Z]/<SOMETHING IN HERE>/g' *.tex
```

How can I grab the last letter of the matching string to use in the replacement regex?

EDIT: For the record, I'm using a BSD version of `sed` (I'm using OS X) - from my [previous question regarding `sed`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525834/pre-pend-word-to-the-last-word-of-a-line), apparently BSD sed (or at least, the Apple version) doesn't always play nice with GNU sed regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right command should be this:

```
sed -i.bak -E "s/\\\@.(\S)/\\\@. \1/g" *.tex
```

Whith it, you match any `\@` followed by non whitespace (`\S`) and insert a whitespace (what is made by replacing the whole match with `'\@ '` plus the the non whitespace just found).

Comment: This doesn't appear to work: `echo '\@.N|\@. Q' | sed -E 's/\\\@.(\S)/\\\@. \1/g'` returns `\@.N|\@. Q` (expecting `\@. N|\@. Q`; no space inserted).

Comment: Strange, because I get the desired result. I'm running sed 4.2.1. Which version is yours?

Comment: Good to know that. Perhaps your version of `sed` has an option to make it behave like GNU sed. But if you have `gsed` then everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use this sed command:

```
sed -i.bak -E 's/(\\@\.)([A-Z])/\1 \2/g' *.tex
```

OR better:

```
sed -i.bak -E 's/(\\@\.)([^ \t])/\1 \2/g' *.tex
```

which will insert space if `\@.` is **not followed by any white-space character** (not just capital letter).

Answer (score 0):

I think the following would be correct:

```
s/\\@\.[^\s]/\\@. /g
```

Only replace the expression if it is not followed by a space.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work: `echo '\@.N|\@. Q' | sed -E 's/\@.[^\s]/\@. /g'` gives me `\@. |\@. Q` (chewed the N).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed -i .bak -E 's/\\@\. \?/\\@. /g' *.tex
```

Explanation:

If there's a space there replace it with a space, otherwise insert a space.