# Selecting a directory in Git filter-branch without a subdirectory

Tags: git

I want to extract a directory from an existing git repo into a new repo.

I am using

```
git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter modules/plugins -- --all
```

as seen on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository/359759#359759), which works nicely.

Now I have a hierarchy of

```
modules/
  plugins/
     foo/
     bar/
     baz/
```

And when filtering I want basically `modules/plugins/*` (which is what the above git command does), BUT not `modules/plugins/bar`.

Is this possible in such a `git filter-branch` expression? If so, how?

With the above expression my new repo ends up as

```
foo/
bar/
baz/
```

How can I keep the `modules/plugins/` part in place?

Comment: Maybe adjust this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519863/git-filter-branch-leave-directory-structure ?

Comment: +Max, Thanks. the second part is the icing on the cake

Answer (score 0):

As I found no way to pass an expression like (imaginary) `--subdirectory-filter modules/plugins,!modules/plugins/bar` I resorted to first run the `git filter-branch` and then afterwards:

```
for B in $BRANCHES; do git checkout -f  $B
  for P in "foo","baz"
  do
    git rm -r --cached $P
  done
  git commit -m "Plugins removed"
done
```

where `$BRANCHES` contains a list of all the branches that have been "activated" before via

```
for B in $BRANCHES ; do  git branch -t $B origin/$B; done
```