# How to use git filter-branch without changing project root?

Tags: git

I have git repo. I want to split a sub directory of the repo into its own separate repo. So, I am using https://help.github.com/en/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository

But the problem is this command changes the project root to the subdirectory. Is there a way I can keep the project root unchanged?

I have tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/9523876/244009 option. This just moves the whole repo one directory deeper.

Comment: What do you mean by "the project root"?

Comment: project root == the directory where the `.git` folder lives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git filter-branch --index-filter '
                git read-tree --empty
                git read-tree --prefix=sub/tree/ $GIT_COMMIT:sub/tree/
        ' -- yourbranch -- sub/tree
```

should do it.